# Image div overlapping preceding div vertically

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with overlapping DIVS. Tried a few things but none have provided the desired outcome. I suspect this is quite easy but i'm missing the key element.

Currently the bingo div overlaps the numbers div. On many screens the numbers div is not even visible as the bingo div takes up the entire screen

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="numbers" style="height:100%">
        <h2>
        What sort of number do you want?    
        </h2>
        <a href="a-level/a1.html">Evens</a>
        <a href="a-level/a2.html">Odds</a>
        <a href="a-level/a3.html">Primes</a>
    </div>

    <div class="bingo">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

h2{
    margin:2rem;    
}

h1{
    margin:-2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

a{
    margin: 0 0 0 2rem;
    border:solid black 1px;
    padding: 0.618rem 1rem;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:black;
}

a:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.bingo{
    bottom:0;
    margin: 4rem 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this problem. I believe the css height property doesn't get changed when you use %, so you may want to use vh. Here is a fiddle I made with 20vh: http://jsfiddle.net/vwtxg94k/6/. 1 vh is relative to 1% of the viewport.

Comment: hmm that appears to have no impact on my end. Added vh in a range of values for both width and height. Doesnt seem to impact it at all

Comment: In the jsfiddle, I added a black border both divs. In this new fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/vwtxg94k/7/ , you can see that they aren't overlapping at all.

Answer (score 0):

The "number" `<div>` takes the height from the contained elements, texts and `<a>`; the point is that the `<a>` elements are `inline` whose CSS height is just the height of the text lines. If they appear to be rectangular on the screen it's just cause you set a padding (that's not added to the parent `<div>` height).
That's causing the overlapping of the rectangles on the "bingo ", but for CSS height there is no overlapping.
The solution is that the "number" `<div>` takes the whole height of the elemets inside it in order to "push down" the "bingo" `<div>` using:

```
a {
  ...
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

I added a bottom margin just to prevent they touch eachother when in a single column at the resize of the screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/hoq97sj5/1/

Comment: I think I get the logic but unfortunately this did not fix it. I found that adding postiion:relative to bingo actually seemed to help, if that is a clue